# ANTLR4 integer parsing fail

Tags: parsing, integer, parser-generator, antlr4

I'm trying to parse a file with antlr 4, I can't get why integer of more than one digit are not parsified 
(line 79:44 no viable alternative at input '17').

This is the entier grammar http://pastebin.com/rxktvUBi

Here is the definition of int

```
fragment DIGIT : [0-9] ;
integer : DIGIT+ ;
```

which doesn't work at all. This version

```
integer : ('0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9')+ ;
```

works only for 1 digit integers.

This is an example of line not parsified

```
 struct p_77_bound_17_or: ((bound(MEK)<=17) | (bound(MEKPP)<=17))
```

The problem is in

```
 simple_expression:

     (integer)+
```

Note that if I use identifier

```
ID:
  ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')+;


identifier: ID;
```

instead of integer

```
 simple_expression:

     identifier
```

that works.

Why? Any Idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `integer` rule is a parser rule, not a lexer rule. The `'0'`, `'1'`, etc. literals it references are implicitly turned into lexer rules which match a single digit each. You should make the following lexer rule instead:

```
INTEGER : '0'..'9'+;
```

Or in ANTLR 4, simply this:

```
INTEGER : [0-9]+;
```